# Autofill a cell when dates are entered in 3 other cells

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I'm trying to create a way to keep track of our jobs by creating a Google spreadsheet.  We can only order our final product when the digital and hard copy proof is approved and we have an order from purchasing. I have columns created for `digital proof approval`, `hard copy proof approval` and `order received`. Is there a way to out fill a 4th column called `Ready to Order` after all of the other columns have something entered in them?

Comment: yes, look into COUNTA

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(COUNTIF(IF(A2:C<>""; ROW(A2:A)); ROW(A2:A))=3; "YES!"; ))
```

[image: 6]